# how to merge data in on-many relation search

Tags: mysql, sql, database

example :

```
table USER: ID                     one
table ROLE: WORK                   many
```

when i do join select, I got data like:

```
ID      WORK
1       cook
1       pilot
1       teacher
```

now I want to get data format like :

```
ID             WORK
1       cook pilot teacher
```

HOW CAN I DO IT? PS:Im USING MYSQL

Comment: You should look into `group_concat`.  Do you have a `userid` in the `role` table or are you trying to produce a `cartesian product` using a `cross join`?  A little unclear...

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT after SELECT to eliminate duplicate values.

example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,WORK
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `group by` and `group_concat()`:

```
select r.user_id,
       group_concat(r.work separator ' '),
from roles r
group by r.user_id;
```